# Select next element with class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For the sake of making this simple, I have two "Featured" blocks, and the first one loads with the class `features-active` applied.

After a timer (in jQuery), I would like to remove the `features-active` class from the first element, and apply it to the **next** block with the `.features` class.

Here's my HTML:

```
<!-- Feature 1 -->

<div class="span3">
  <div class="features drop-shadow features-active">
    <h4><strong>SUPER</strong> RESPONSIVE</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Feature 2 -->

<div class="span3">
  <div class="features drop-shadow">
    <h4><strong>SUPER</strong> RESPONSIVE</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My only question (I feel retarded today) is - After my timer fires, how do I select the next `.features` element that comes after the `div.features-active` ?**

Here's my jQuery that does not work:

```
var nextFeature = $('div.features-active').next('div.features');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all the wasted overhead by using .next(), .parent(), .children(), .find(), etc, just use the index of the featured elements.

```
var idx = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    $('div.features').removeClass('features-active');
    $('div.features').eq(idx).addClass('features-active');
    idx++;
}, 2000);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g5Czy/2/)**

Comment: With your solution, how can I loop back to the first element when I reach the last?

Comment: Easy, just add one line: `if(idx==$('div.features').length)idx=0;`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/g5Czy/3/

Comment: One more question... How can I pause the timer on `mouseenter` and resume on `mouseleave`?

Comment: You'd need to use clearInterval on mouseenter, and then start another setinterval on mouseleave. With that functionality you'd probably want to move the code outside of the setInterval call and into its own function.

Comment: Ok.. I did that... so how can I tell it to resume at the block it left off on? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5Czy/5/

Comment: `idx` will keep track of that as long as it's a global variable.

Comment: Is it better to use `hover` over `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` ?

Comment: Either. From the docs: The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply `.next()` on the node's parent.

```
var nextFeature = $('div.features-active').parent('div.span3')
                                          .next('div.span3')
                                          .children('div.features');
```

Comment: With your alternative method just using `next()`, how would this look?

Comment: @AdamD, edited. The `div.span3` selectors are for sanity check

Comment: I don't need the `:has()` - the `next()` method works just fine. Thanks! :)

Comment: @AdamD, I removed the `:has()` alternative. It's really overkill :)

Comment: One more question... how can I select the FIRST occurrence of `.features` after the timer runs on the Feature 2 element? (in other words, after reaching the end of the series of Featured blocks, loop back to the first `.features` element)

Comment: You can search the first occurrence in the DOM, `$("div.features:first")`. Or, simply save it for later

Answer (score 1):

There is no next `.features`, they have different parents ?

```
var nextFeature = $('div.features-active').closest('.span3')
                                          .next('.span3')
                                          .find('div.features')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/umTPw/

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('.features').removeClass('features-active').promise().done(function () {
      $(this).parent().next().find('.features').addClass('features-active');
   });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
var nextFeature = $('div.features-active').next().find('div.features');
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `div.features-active` .next() doesn't give you an element because it has no siblings.